# Turn a partial into a json variable in the controller

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I need to turn the html of a partial into a json object (NOT TO BE RENDERED), but to be stored in a seperate format.

Something like this:

```
  @json = (:partial => "/answers/likers" ,:type => :html)
```

Although the above obviously does not work, but hope you get the point, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`render_to_string`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string). It takes the same arguments as `render`, and just returns a string instead of outputting the data.

It looks like it's being deprecated but I can't find any new method that provides that same functionality for Rails 3. I tested it on a local Rails 3 setup, though, and it works for me. If anyone knows the "new" way to do this in Rails 3 please let me know, I'm interested now :)

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a .to_json function. However, I never used this together with a partial ...